# NullPointerException when trying to add to local initialized arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I created a rectangle array to store my snake body. In the grow method, I create a local ArrayList and initialize it, adding the content of the rectangle array. Then I try to add new rectangle to the ArrayList, however at this point, I receive NullPointerException, and I'm not sure why and how to fix it. I've tried searching it up on google and on this website, however I did not find a topic with this problem.

```
public class Snake extends GameObject
{
    private Rectangle[] snake;
    private int speed;

    public Snake(int locX, int locY, int width, int height, int speed, ID id) 
    {
        super(locX, locY, width, height, id);
        snake = new Rectangle[3];
        snake[0] = new Rectangle(locX, locY, width, height);
        this.speed = speed;
        grow();
    }

    public void render(Graphics g) 
    {
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        drawSnake(g);               
    }   

    public Rectangle getBounds()
    {
        return new Rectangle(locX, locY, width, height);
    }   

    private void drawSnake(Graphics g)
    {       
        for(int i = 0; i < snake.length - 1; i++)
        {
            g.fillRect(locX, locY, width, height);
        }
    }

    private void grow()
    {
        ArrayList<Rectangle> tempBody = new ArrayList<Rectangle>(Arrays.asList(snake));

        tempBody.add(new Rectangle(snake[snake.length - 1].x, snake[snake.length - 1].y, width, height));   

        snake = tempBody.toArray(snake);
    }   
}
```

Comment: share the stacktrace

Comment: Will the Rectangle you add have the same position ? or like increase  ?

Answer (score 4):

Here why :

- `snake = new Rectangle[3];` : you create an array for 3 `Rectangle`

  1. so `snake` is`[null, null, null]`
- `snake[0] = new Rectangle(locX, locY, width, height);` : you fill the first box with an object

  2. so `snake` is`[rect, null, null]`
- `snake[snake.length - 1].x` you want to get the `Rectangle` of the last box, but refer to *2.* : this box contains `null`, so you call `null.x`-> *NPE*

---

To improve, you can add an attribute `size`, and when you want to `grow()` you'll add a Rectangle at this place like :

```
private void grow(){
    ArrayList<Rectangle> tempBody = new ArrayList<Rectangle>(Arrays.asList(snake));

    tempBody.add(new Rectangle(snake[size].x, 
                               snake[size].y, width, height));   

    snake = tempBody.toArray(snake);
    size++;
}
```

**#** But a real better way would be to use `List<Rectangle> snake` and never use an array (if possible) because you need a size-mutable element so `List` is perfect

*I would suggest that the `Rectangle` you add won't have the same position ? But here you'll have to decide*

Comment: perhaps offer OP a way to fine what index to use when trying to grow the body (search the array for the first null and use the that index found - 1 to find the tail of the snake)

Comment: One more mistake that I can see is that when he is adding a new Rectangle in tempBody where is he getting the width and height? He is  not passing it as a parameter to the grow() function, its not defined in the grow() function, neither are they global variables.

Comment: @HarilSatra look constructor, there are from superclass `GameObject`

Comment: I suggest getting rid of the array and using a list instead. Futher just starting with one element not three, where two are null.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to offer a solution to the grow() method that will add a body (rectangle) to the current tail of the snake by adding it to the next null location in the snake array without going out of the bounds of the array. I am assuming OP converted the snake array into the arraylist to get the current size of the snake, and then you wanted to use that size - 1 as your index to grab the tail of your snake to use its member variables for the new body being added to the snake.

```
public void grow()
{
    ArrayList<Rectangle> tempBody = new ArrayList<Rectangle>(Arrays.asList(snake));
    if(tempBody.size() < snake.length())
    {
        tempBody.add(new Rectangle(snake[tempBody.size() - 1].x, snake[tempBody.size() - 1].y, width, height));   
        snake = tempBody.toArray(snake);
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Snake at full size: " + snake.length());
}
```

Comment: The goadl to use the List, is to increase size indefinitly, after 2 times grow you'll go always in else but you still can grow